# Nativescript TypeError: " Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined " after upgrading NS 6.0

Tags: nativescript

After upgrading NS 6.0 I got "Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined" even I don't use this method.

I am using firebase plugins and this crash happens right after firebase configuration at the very beginning

Comment: It's possible one of your plugin is accessing undefined values. Are you using only Firebase plugin? Did you upgrade that too?

Comment: yes I use firebase and it is updated latest

Comment: Please share a sample project where the issue can be reproduced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What other plugins/hooks are you using? I was getting a "Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined" error immediately after "Configure firebase". For me the issue was nativescript-fabric.

https://www.nativescript.org/blog/migrating-cli-hooks-to-nativescript-6.0 describes the changes made to hooks that includes a new data structure for hookArgs. In my case, the hook was setting the platform using the following:

```
var platform = hookArgs.platform.toLowerCase();
```

The hookArgs object has changed in Nativescript 6. hookArgs doesn't have a platform property. Instead, it has the following definition:

```
hookArgs: {
    platformData,
    projectData,
    prepareData
}
```

In updated plugins, the following is used:

```
var platform = (hookArgs.platform || (hookArgs.prepareData && hookArgs.prepareData.platform)).toLowerCase();
```